# Add "DATE()" to Doctrine2 SQL in Zend Framework 2 Project

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I was hopeful to add MySQL's DATE to my Doctrine setup in my ZF2 app.  I've done what the documentation claims is necessary:

In my module's `onMergeConfig`

```
$config['doctrine']['connection']['orm_default']['datetime_functions'] = [
    'date' => 'Erudite\Doctrine\DQL\Date',
]
// ...
$configListener->setMergedConfig($config);
```

...I had tried configuring through `module.config.php` as well, same deal...

I've added Date as such:

```
namespace Erudite\Doctrine\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;


class Date extends FunctionNode
{
    public $date;

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return "DATE(" . $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticPrimary($this->date) . ")";
    }
    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->date = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

This unfortunately causes this error:

```
An abstract factory could not create an instance of doctrine.entitymanager.ormdefault(alias: doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default).
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken (no time to check, on my way out), but isn't the correct key for your custom function `$config['doctrine']['configuration']['orm_default']['datetime_functions']` ? (`configuration` rather than `connection`). Also, it might help others offer a diagnosis if you edited your question and added a link to the documentation you mentioned.

Comment: @Crisp damn that was it.  Post it as an answer I'll give you credit.

Comment: No probs, and done, glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct config key for your custom function should be

`$config['doctrine']['configuration']['orm_default']['datetime_functions']`

(`configuration` rather than `connection`)